# Issues with Secret Key when deploying Django App to Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, environment-variables

I keep getting

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

when trying to deploy my django app to heroku. I'm using `python-dotenv` and my `settings.py` file looks like this:

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("DJANGO_SECRET_KEY")
```

And the `.env` file (which is in my `.gitignore` file has the DJANGO SECRET KEY stored:

`export DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=mykeyhere`

I'm using pipenv if it helps - everything is working fine locally, but heroku doesn't seem to pick up on the variable.

Any thoughts?

(I also tried adding the secret key as a config variable on the heroku dashboard without success)

Comment: Have you tried using Django-Heroku along with dotenv? https://pypi.org/project/django-heroku/

Comment: As you say, the env file is *ignored*. How exactly did you try to add it in Heroku?

Comment: I tried adding it on the dashboard in heroku - there's a "set config variables". Not sure how I would do it through terminal when the .env file is in `.gitignore`

Comment: Any ideas? Not sure how to proceed